# Using javascript to insert links in text WITHOUT replacing entire content of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a widget that searches for specific keywords in a specified "#content" div.

Here is how I set it up originally using jQuery (simplified version):

- set a variable equal to the html of the content: `var content = $('content').html();`
- use some regexes to replace certain keywords with `<a href='link.html'>keyword</a>`
- replace the html of the content div with the new content: `$('content').html(content);`

This works for the most part, but the problem occurs when the "#content" div contains javascript. When I set `$('content').html(content)`, it re-runs any javascript code contained in the `$('content')` div, which can cause errors. Since this is a widget that I'm writing to work on any site, I don't have control over the content div, and whether there will be any javascript in it.

My questions is, is there a way to replace JUST the keywords with `<a href='link.html'>keyword</a>`, WITHOUT replacing the entire content of the div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My questions is, is there a way to replace JUST the keywords with `<a href='link.html'>keyword</a>`, WITHOUT replacing the entire content of the div?

Yes. It's one of the (few) places where jQuery doesn't really offer you much.

Down at the raw DOM API level, though, the [`Text` node](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) containing the actual text of the element has a [`splitText` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-38853C1D) with which you can split the node into two adjacent nodes at a specific location. So in your case, you'd split at the beginning of the word and then again after the end of it, then wrap that middle `Text` node in a new anchor.

Here's an example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/afiwun) | [source](http://jsbin.com/afiwun/edit)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Make it a link">
<p id="example">This is the example paragraph.</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    var targetWord, p, textNode, index, nodeWord, nodeAfter;

    // Our target word
    targetWord = "example";

    // Get the paragraph using jQuery; note that after we
    // use jQuery to get it (because it fixes getElementById for
    // us on older versions of IE), we then use [0] to access
    // the *raw* `p` element.
    // Then get the text node from it.
    p = $("#example")[0];
    textNode = p.firstChild;

    // Find our text in the text node
    index = textNode.nodeValue.indexOf(targetWord);
    if (index !== -1) {
      // Split at the beginning of the text
      nodeWord = textNode.splitText(index);

      // Split the new node again at the end of the word
      nodeAfter = nodeWord.splitText(targetWord.length);

      // Insert a new anchor in front of the word
      anchor = document.createElement('a');
      anchor.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
      p.insertBefore(anchor, nodeWord);

      // Now move the word *into* the anchor
      anchor.appendChild(nodeWord);
    }
  });

});
```

Naturally there are some things you'd want to do to improve that:

- Handle the `index === 0` case without creating an empty text node at the beginning of the parent element. *(Harmless, but less than ideal.)*
- Handle the case where the word is at the very *end* of the parent, so you don't end up with an empty text node there. *(Again.)*

Comment: @carboneau: Good deal, glad that helped.

Answer (score 3):

you can replace only keywords without replacing all content like this,

```
function keywordconvert(str, p1, offset, s)  {
      return "<a href=\"link?t="+encodeURIComponent(p1)+"\">"+p1+"</a>";
}

function search(keyword) {
   var content = document.getElementById("content");
   var re = new RegExp("("+keyword+")","g");
  content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML.replace(re, keywordconvert);
}
```

**USAGE**

```
search("keyword");
```

​​

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JHHzU/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you would have to loop through all text nodes manually.

Far easier would be to strip `<script>` tags first, because once they have been run they are not needed on the page (everything is kept in memory).

```
$('#content script').remove();
```

That will remove the scripts from the `#content` element, then you can run your existing replace code without problems.